# The actual number of row of Lazy Spool is huge

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan

The SQL Server execution plan shows the Lazy spool has 7935322 actual number of rows, but its child operator only has 32 rows.

```
Nested Loop (Inner Join, 2 rows)   <--- Hash match(3967661 rows)
       ^
       |
       +--- Lazy Spool (7935322 rows)  <-- Merge Join (32 rows)
```

If lazy spool sourced from its child rows as a temp table, it should only have 32 rows at maximum. I don't understand why does it have 7935322 rows.

```
Lazy Spool properties

Actual Rebinds: 16 
Actual Rewinds: 3967645
Number of Executions: 3967661

Nested Loop properties:

Actual Number of Rows: 2
Number of Executions: 16
```

Comment: One of child operator produce 32 rows.There must be one more child operator.And join of these 2 child operator result in Lazy spool with rewind and rebind.you hvn't mention  about other operator.So may be join between these 2 child operator is wrong including filter condition.

Answer (score 1):

Spool operator ( “Lazy” Spool in this case) will create a temporary table in the TempDB database, and store all data (32 rows in this case) returned from the Merge join.

Nested loop join executed 3967661 times (outer input) and did a join with table spool (holding 32 rows).  Out of 3967661 times 16 times the parameter of the join changed and had to reevaluate the inner result set (rebind) and 3967645 times inner result set was reusable. As I am not seeing the whole plan I believe 7935322 number came form the 16 reevaluating the inner data set.

In most cases creating an index will most likely get rid of the spool and make the query run faster.  Because you do not have to create the temporary table in tempdb.

Comment: The Nested Loops shows only 2 actual number of rows.  That means there are only 2 rows after inner join with 3967661 rows (outer loop) and 32 rows (inner loop). What are 7935322 rows indeed?

Comment: can you paste the whole plan [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/).

Comment: Very sorry for that, but firm policy does not allow to.

Comment: @buzz try using Plan Explorer to anonymize your plan, if company policy won't permit posting actual plans. https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer

Comment: Note that 3967661 * 2 = 79335322. One suspects that's relevant in some way.